# Is WebSocket hardware dependant?

Tags: javascript, browser, websocket

Does using a recent browser that supports WebSocket automatically means the client can use WebSocket? Or is there other external hardware requirements?

Ex: To use WebGL, you need a browser that supports WebGL AND a graphic card that supports it. Is it the same for WebSocket?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, WebSocket is just a network communications protocol ([RFC 6455](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6455)), implemented in software, with no special hardware requirements.

Comment: WebSocket piggybacks on the same networking infrastructure that the browser already uses to access websites. The HTML page uses scripting to access the browser's WebSocket API, asking the browser to make a connection to a server and then read/send WebSocket-formatted data packets back and forth.  The browser handles the actual networking like with any other socket connection it makes.

Answer (score 1):

No, you don't need any specific hardware to use WebSockets.